# Page is not Scrolling Fully because of Expanded

Tags: android, flutter, dart, scroll

When I remove `SingleChildScrollView` and use the property `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` The code works fine and the scrolling works, But by doing this I the scroll only works for this widget `NewsItem` which is at the end of the page and the scroll is actually working only for the `NewsItem` rather for the whole page which Is what I wanna acheive.

Here is the code,

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
            // .... Some Widgets that take the 70% of the screen 
              Expanded(
                // height: 500,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) {
                    return const NewsItem(
                      image:
                          'https://media.giphy.com/media/fTn01fiFdTd5pL60ln/giphy.gif',
                      headline: "Joe was attacked again! Lmaooooo",
                      author: 'Jack Williams',
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

By wrapping the
`NewsItem` with the `Expanded` widget leaves no room for scroll unless I replace it with `SizedBox` But it only enables for me to scroll down the whole page where am seeing 3 of the `NewsItem` instead of 5 as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify things by using the spread operator `...` to add a generated list of widgets:

```
body: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
  child: ListView(
    children: [
      // .... Some Widgets that take the 70% of the screen
      // Use the spread operator to add a generated list of NewsItems with length 5
      ...List<Widget>.generate(
        5,
        (index) {
          // [index] is the position in the generated list (from 0 up to 4 in this case)
          return const NewsItem(
            image: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/fTn01fiFdTd5pL60ln/giphy.gif',
            headline: 'Joe was attacked again! Lmaooooo',
            author: 'Jack Williams',
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the items that you want in your listview to the column, after all of your other widgets that take up 70% of the screen.

```
final newsItems = [1,2,3,4,5]; // Just an example list

SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
            // .... Some Widgets that take the 70% of the screen
            ...newsItems.map(item => const NewsItem(
                      image:
                          'https://media.giphy.com/media/fTn01fiFdTd5pL60ln/giphy.gif',
                      headline: "Joe was attacked again! Lmaooooo",
                      author: 'Jack Williams',
                    );
                ).toList(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

newsItems is then simply the list of News Items you want to display.